# Confusion about pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault, null-pointer

I am working on some code where I call two functions.

- `function1(SerializedMsg *source, void *target)` deserializes the information in `source` and fills `target` with it.
- `function2(std::shared_ptr<Msg> &msg)`. To this function I feed messages created with `function1`.

My problem relates to pointers, I believe. I have tried two approaches:

```
std::shared_ptr<Msg> msg;

function1(&source, &msg)

function2(msg)
```

This resulted in error -11 (SIGSEGV) at runtime, I believe due to trying to access a pointer's memory address, although I'm certainly not sure.

```
std::shared_ptr<Msg> msg;

void *void_ptr;

function1(&source, void_ptr)

msg = * static_cast<std::shared_ptr<Msg>*> (void_ptr);

function2(msg)
```

This results in error -6 (SIGABRT), due to an exception thrown by `function1` because it was passed a null pointer as its second parameter.

Everything else that I have tried refuses to compile, so I refrained from including it here, but can if necessary.

Thanks in advance, and please excuse my poor knowledge of pointers and C++ in general - I wouldn't be surprised if this had a very simple solution.

Comment: If you're only ever going to pass std::shared_ptr<Msg> types to function1 then you should not be using a void pointer. There are few cases where this is warranted and this doesn't look like one of them. Also from your definition of function2 it takes a reference not a pointer.

Comment: The memory that is pointed to by target passed to function1 must be allocated first. This is not being done in your second code snippet, which will cause a seg fault. I really recommend using a pointer or reference to std::shared_ptr<Msg> in function1 for this.

Comment: If you want help with an error in code, you have to show the part of the code that contains the error. The best way to ensure that is to provide a [mre].

Comment: Your first approach clobbers the `shared_ptr<Msg>` object -- it is not writing to the Msg object that the shared pointer would point to if it had been given one. Your second approach writes to wherever `void_ptr` points -- and since it is uninitialized, that's UB.

Comment: Besides the object clobber, the first shouldn't even compile. If the prototype for `function2` truly is `function2(std::shared_ptr<Msg> &msg)` it expects a *reference* to a mutable `std::shared_ptr<Msg>`; you've giving it a *pointer* to a `std::shared_ptr<Msg>`. They're not compatible at compile-time, much-less runnable to a fault. That little oversight is one reason we need a proper [mcve].

Comment: @PeteBlackerThe3rd Unfortunately the first function is out of my control, and asks for a `voidptr`. Initialising the message with `make_shared` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using pointer you need to take care where they point to and if there is some valid memory.

Taking your first approach:

```
std::shared_ptr<Msg> msg;
function1(&source, &msg);
```

You pass in the shared_ptr so the `void*` in you function points to the memory of a shared_ptr. Not the memory the shared_ptr points to.
But we can fix this.

```
std::shared_ptr<Msg> msg;
function1(&source, msg.get());
```

This will pass in the pointer the shared_ptr points to. But this is the same as doing something like this.

```
function1(&source, nullptr);
```

The shared_ptr is not initialized so it cannot point to a valid object in memory. So the shared_ptr will point to null.

So to make your function work we need some real memory

```
Msg msg{};
function1(&source, &msg);

auto msg = std::make_shared<Msg>();
function1(&source, msg.get());
```

So in the first case you create the object on the stack. Maybe this ok for mabe not. That depends on the use case.
In the second case we put a default constructed object into a shared_ptr and let your function fill it with data.
In both cases we now have a valid Message.

But in general you should consider reworking the API of your functions. Don't use `void*`, in modern c++ it is barely needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Initialising with `make_shared` worked wonders!